# Select NULL columns without using "IS NULL"

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I need to select all the NULL records in my database which have the column called `"cliente_pretenece"`

The problem is that I can't define it inside the sql query using `IS NULL`, because I am using different criteria’s for select, here is the select code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1";
if (!empty($id)) {
  $sql .= " AND userID = '$id' ";
}
if (!empty($telefono)) {
  $sql .= " AND telefono LIKE '%$telefono%' ";
}
if (!empty($cliente_pretenece)) {
  $sql .= " AND cliente_pretenece = '$cliente_pretenece' ";
}
```

the column cliente_pretence will always have 3 different states, and the select code from whch the call is coming is:

```
<select>
<option  value="SDQ">State 1</option>
<option  value="SA">State 2</option>
<option  value="NULL">Nothing</option>
</select>
```

So any help will be very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `IS NULL`. Modify your code so that it reacts differently to the NULL value and generates an `IS NULL` test instead of a comparison.

Also, learn about parametrized queries before you get an SQL injection.

Comment: this code is for local use only it is not used in internet.

Comment: That's no excuse to be lazy. Besides what if a user enters a `'` character? They'll get an error.

Comment: there isn't any <input>'s only select tags so the user don't have an option to write anything. The code is really old and I need a simple modification in other cases I have to revriew the whole system and that goal doesn't fit in the time frame.

Comment: Where does `$telefono` come from?

Comment: <option  value="yes">Telefono</option>
  <option  value="no">No Telefono</option>

Comment: Why are you using a LIKE for something like that

Comment: I was using it for testing in another code, which looks like I forgot to change it once I've used it here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50741/discussion-between-john-siniger-and-matti-virkkunen)